# class and functions in python

Tags: python, function, class, python-3.x

I'm new to Python and I'm trying classes and objects, I have this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class test:
    def __init__(self, username):

        self.username = username

    def name_again(self):

        for i in range(0-4):
            print ("username is %s" %self.username)

ahmed = test('ahmbor')

ahmed.name_again()
```

I'm expecting this script to print "username is ahmbor" 5 times 
When I run this script, I have nothing
Please help find what's wrong with this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are telling `range()` to loop over **`0-4`** (subtract four from zero), which is `-4`. Because the default is to start at 0 and count *up*, that is an empty range:

```
>>> range(0-4)
range(0, -4)
>>> len(range(0-4))
0
```

Use a comma instead, and use *5* to loop 5 times, not 4. The endpoint is not included:

```
>>> len(range(0, 4))
4
>>> len(range(0, 5))
5
```

Comment: the start point defaults to 0 anyway, so you don't need that.

Comment: @Eevee: indeed, but the OP clearly wanted to explicitly define the starting point.